# Reverse string printing using carriage return

Tags: c, carriage-return

I wanted to reverse my name using carriage return as it passes the control of cursor back to the beginning of line and so if I use `A\ra\rs\rh\ri\rs\rh` the firstly A would be printing and I thought that the next thing to get printed before `A` would be `a` and before that `s` and so on, till the letter becomes `hsihsaA` (from `Aashish`) as expected output but as it turns out , it just created `hA` as output, why so ??

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf(" A\ra\rs\rh\ri\rs\rh\n");   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with C (apart from the fact that in C, you just have a stream representing your *standard output*, taking characters in sequence).

It depends on whatever the (virtual) terminal that receives your output as input does in response to your control characters. An output of just `hA` would be reasonable if the result of `\r` is just to begin again at the beginning of the current line. This is, if your terminal overwrites the character that is already there. <strike>Your terminal seems to be doing something different and weird, but whatever it is, it is out of the control of your program.</strike> After the edit, your terminal obviously does exactly that. It's the most likely output, but I wouldn't count on every terminal behaving in exactly that way.

If you want to control your terminal, I suggest you use an implementation of the `curses` library -- read more in the [NCURSES Programming HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). Control of a terminal is not part of the language C, but `curses` is a *de facto* standard for it, working on many systems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, I get an output `h`, which is what *I expect.*

Once you move the cursor to the beginning of line and start printing, the previous output is *overwritten*. Thus, only the last output remains. Since normally the standard output is line buffered, thus, the `\n` in the end causes the buffer to be flushed in the end and the visible output is `h`.

The intermediate changes, well, will not be *visible*, so I don't expect you will be able to *print in reverse*, as you may expect.

My system info:

```
[broadsword@ph-ds-yyafe-3 temp]# gcc test1.c
[broadsword@ph-ds-yyafe-3 temp]# ./a.out
h
[broadsword@ph-ds-yyafe-3 temp]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[broadsword@ph-ds-yyafe-3 temp]#
```

Comment: Now I get it , I had actually used " A\ra\rs\rh\ri\rs\rh\n" rather than "A\ra\rs\rh\ri\rs\rh\n" in my program and when \r is used then the space between ' ' and 'a' is overwritten to produce ha.

Comment: @AashishLoknathPanigrahi well, there you go. (I don't see the space yet, though).